# How to conditionally include files in build?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, xsd, msbuild

MSBuild has an [`ExcludedFromBuild`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171455.aspx) which excludes a file based on condition. I want the opposite pattern - I want to include a file based on a condition.

It appears I cannot add a condition to an `ItemGroup`, which is the node source files are included. Also see [Why the `Condition` attribute doesn't work for the `ItemGroup` element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28851338) So something like this does not work:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)'=='x64'">
  <ClCompile Include="x64.cpp" />
</ItemGroup>
```

How do I conditionally include files in build?

---

The reason for the change is we are adding better support for ARM. We think the project files can be re-purposed by adding an ARM section like X86 and X64:

```
<!-- X86 Configurations -->
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Platform)'=='Win32'" Label="X86 Configuration">
  <ClCompile>
    <EnableEnhancedInstructionSet>StreamingSIMDExtensions2</EnableEnhancedInstructionSet>
  </ClCompile>
  <Link>
    <TargetMachine>MachineX86</TargetMachine>
  </Link>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>

<!-- X64 Configurations -->
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Platform)'=='x64'" Label="X64 Configuration">
  <ClCompile>
    <EnableEnhancedInstructionSet>StreamingSIMDExtensions2</EnableEnhancedInstructionSet>
  </ClCompile>
  <Link>
    <TargetMachine>MachineX64</TargetMachine>
  </Link>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

However, we have this *unscalable* wart code, and I feel it should be re-written to *include* on x64 platforms (whitelist), rather than *exclude* on non-x64 platforms (blacklist). Its obviously going to break on ARM, and it will break again if Microsoft supports MIPS for IoT.

```
<CustomBuild Include="x64masm.asm">
  <Message>Building and Assembling x64masm.asm</Message>    
  <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Platform)'=='Win32'">true</ExcludedFromBuild>
  <Command>ml64.exe /c /nologo /D_M_X64 /W3 /Fo"$(IntDir)x64masm.obj" /Zi "%(FullPath)"</Command>
  <Outputs>$(IntDir)x64masm.obj;%(Outputs)</Outputs>
</CustomBuild>
```

Comment: Why don't you set the condition on your `CustomBuild`? `<CustomBuild Include="x64masm.asm" Condition="'$(Platform)'=='x64'">`

Comment: @Troopers - We probably can for the ASM code; I'll have to look it up to see if its allowed. But we also have code that's cpu specific in `arm_cpu.cpp`, `x86_cpu.cpp`, etc. The CPP files don't have custom build rules.

Comment: You could create a target CustomBuild that call special targets for arm, win32 et x64. Then add special Item in a ItemGroup in this targets then call the default Build

Comment: Thanks @Troopers. The best I can tell [MSBuild does not support ARM](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39902108). I'm fairly sure the exercise above is a moot point. I'll leave the question open rather than deleting it in case someone has the insight to share for others.

Comment: Seems this issue is based on issue of MSBuild does not support ARM.