# Condition in csproj is ignored

Tags: .net-core, csproj

When I am running "dotnet publish --runtime=linux-x64 -c Release" the libusb-1.0.pdb file is added to the publish folder even though the condition flag is set to different than Release

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\lib\Windows\libusb-1.0.pdb" Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Release'">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\lib\Windows\libusb-1.0.pdb" Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Release'">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: see: [Why the `Condition` attribute doesn't work for the `ItemGroup` element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28851338/why-the-condition-attribute-doesnt-work-for-the-itemgroup-element)

Comment: I'm not sure but try these options: 1) Set the condition on the ItemGroup element - OR 2) Try the inverse: if Release, Content Remove. 3) For every change to the .csproj, reload the project and rebuild it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you reference a `.dll` file in the same location, MSBuild will pick up "related files" automatically. You can work around this by limiting the extensions of related files:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Release'">
  <AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>
    .xml;
    .pri;
    .dll.config;
    .exe.config
  </AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Note that this is a copy of what can be found in the .NET SDK in `Microsoft.Common.props` but without an entry for `.pdb`.

Do note that you should no longer need to include the `.pdb` file as a `Content` item. If you do, you need to also keep your original definition for that item.